OpenCV - Detect triangles within detected rectangle in real-time video
For a project I want to detect the edges of triangular shapes within a detected rectangular object (tray) in real-time on a Raspberry Pi IR camera, for the follow up to a next step.
For now I've detected the edges of the tray and made a four point transform of it, see the image below.
Detected tray:

For the next step, when a unique combination of contours (rectangle containing 2 triangles) is detected, the message 'Tray detected' and the four point transform screen has to be displayed. Something like this:
Detected tray with triangles:

Any advice? Thanks for the help
Code:
import numpy as np
import cv2
import imutils
from picamera2 import Picamera2
from imutils.perspective import four_point_transform

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 1280, 720

piCam = Picamera2()
piCam.preview_configuration.main.size=(1280,720)
piCam.preview_configuration.main.format = "RGB888"
piCam.preview_configuration.align()
piCam.configure("preview")
piCam.start()

def scan_detection (koptray):
    global document_contour

    document_contour = np.array([[0,0], [WIDTH, 0], [WIDTH, HEIGHT], [0, HEIGHT]])

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(koptray, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)                
    blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray,(5,5),1.4)
    edges = cv2.Canny(blur, 10, 20)
    _, threshold = cv2.threshold(blur, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

    contours,_ = cv2.findContours(threshold, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    contours = sorted(contours, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)

    max_area = 0
    for contour in contours:
        area = cv2.contourArea(contour)
        if area > 1000:
            peri = cv2.arcLength(contour, True)
            approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(contour, 0.03 * peri, True)
            if area > max_area and len(approx) == 4:
                document_contour = approx
                max_area = area
    
    cv2.drawContours(frame, [document_contour], -1, (0, 255, 0), 3)

    return blur, edges

while True:
    frame = piCam.capture_array()
    frame_copy = frame.copy()

    scan_detection(frame_copy)
    cv2.imshow("IRCam", frame)

    warped = four_point_transform(frame_copy, document_contour.reshape(4, 2))
    cv2.imshow("Warped", warped)

    blur, edges = scan_detection(warped)
    cv2.imshow("Blur", blur)
    cv2.imshow("Edges", edges)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

I've tried:

detecting the edges of triangles with the elif len(approx) == 3: line, but they are only being detected outside of the rectangle.

Set the area to detect between two values if 1000 < area < 100000


